# how to remove area text from google charts

Tags: graph, google-visualization

iam using google charts for displaying statistics, i use a term called visits to show statistics, the area text shows the name, i want to remove the area text, please see the image below
[image]

How to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

While you are creating the data array you can decide whether show it or not.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Minutes', ''], ***//if you left the second item '' empty then it will disappear.***
        [ '5'  , 12 ],
        [ '10' , 34 ],
        [ '15' , 56 ]
        ]);
```